# AVAudioPlayer not smooth when play via bluetooth

Tags: iphone, audio

I use AVAudioPlayer to play music file. It just works well when playing via headphone or speaker on iPhone body. But not smooth when playing via bluetooth. Why?

Here is my code:

```
AVAudioPlayer *newMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:musicData error:&error];
if (!newMusicPlayer)
{
}
else
{
    [newMusicPlayer play];
}
```

Special thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an apple's bug on 3GS running ios5.1.1, because "Music" is not smooth too.